# I want to create laravel web page that have 4 kind user privilege

Tags: laravel, laravel-8, laravel-authentication

I'm newbie in Laravel, and i have to create web that have 4 kinds user and im going to use MySQL as database. Anyone have some suggestion what should i do or have helpful tutorial link from website or youtube? its kinda hard to find it because it is Laravel 8.

So, here is the detail
User type :

- Staff
- Supervisor
- Head Unit
- Manager

And in login page if the account is staff will be directed into staff page, if the account is manager it will directed into manager page

Thanks in advance

Comment: There are a variety of packages like https://github.com/spatie/laravel-permission that will help you do this sort of thing. Laravel 5, 6, 7, and 8 tutorials will all be fairly similar, too - each new version adds some neat features, but the basics remain pretty much the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way i could think of is to define it in your blade code using an if statement like this :

```
        @if(Auth::user()->role_id == '1')
    
  ///// if the user role is 1 this will show /////

        @endif

        @if(Auth::user()->role_id == '2')
    
  ///// if the user role is 2 this will show /////

        @endif
```

and so on...

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have some kind of role/permissions package implemented, in your LoginController, implement a method called `authenticated`:

```php
/**
 * The user has been authenticated.
 *
 * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
 * @param  mixed  $user
 * @return mixed
 */
protected function authenticated(Request $request, $user)
{
    switch ($user->role) {
        case 'Manager':
            return redirect('/url/to/manager/view');
        case 'Supervisor':
            ...
    }
}
```